# D3 Legend not updating

Tags: javascript, d3.js

hoping you can help point out my mistake here...

I can't get the second row of the legend to update on mouseover of the histogram:

I don't believe it's the selector because you can add an id attribute to both no problem, and the data seems to be coming through ok on a console.log() ...little bit baffled.

http://jsfiddle.net/2sgLjbvu/3/

```
var data = [
    {Supplier:"Supplier A",val: {WIP:"500",Conv:"400"}},
    {Supplier:"Supplier B",val: {WIP:"1400",Conv:"400"}},
    {Supplier:"Supplier C",val: {WIP:"300",Conv:"800"}},
    {Supplier:"Supplier D",val: {WIP:"1000",Conv:"200"}}
];

dashboard("#chartArea",data);

function dashboard(id,fData){
    var barColor='steelblue';
    function segColor(c){return {WIP:"#807dba",Conv:"#41ab5d"}[c];}

//compute total for each supplier
fData.forEach(function (d){d.total = parseFloat(d.val.WIP) + parseFloat(d.val.Conv);});

//func to handle histogram
function histoGram(fD){
    //Dimensions
    var hG={}, hGDim = {t:60,r:0,b:30,l:0};
    hGDim.w = 500 - hGDim.l - hGDim.r,
    hGDim.h = 300 - hGDim.t - hGDim.b;

    //create svg for histogram.
    var hGsvg = d3.select(id).append("svg")
        .attr("width",hGDim.w +hGDim.l + hGDim.r)
        .attr("height",hGDim.h + hGDim.t + hGDim.b)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(" + hGDim.l + "," + hGDim.t + ")");

    //create function for x-axis mapping
    var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0,hGDim.w],0.1)
        .domain(fD.map(function(d){return d[0];}));
    //Add x-axis to histogram
    hGsvg.append("g")
        .attr("class","x axis")
        .attr("transform","translate(0," + hGDim.h + ")")
        .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));
    //create function for y-axis mapping
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([hGDim.h,0])
        .domain([0,d3.max(fD,function(d){
                return d[1];
        })]);
    //create bars for the histogram to contain recs and val labels
    var bars = hGsvg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(fD)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class","bar");
    //create the recs
    bars.append("rect")
        .attr("x",function(d){return x(d[0]);})
        .attr("y",function(d){return y(d[1]);})
        .attr("width",x.rangeBand())
        .attr("height",function(d){return hGDim.h - y(d[1]);})
        .attr("fill",barColor)
        .on("mouseover",mouseover) //defined below
        .on("mouseout",mouseout); //defined below
    function mouseover(d){
        //filter for selected supplier
        var st = fData.filter(function(s){return s.Supplier==d[0];})[0],
            nD = d3.keys(st.val).map(function(s){return {type:s,val:st.val[s]};});

        pC.update(nD);
        leg.update(nD);
    }
    function mouseout(d){
        //reset the pie-chart and legend
        pC.update(tF);
        leg.update(tF);
    }
    //func to update the bars - this will be used by the pie-chart
    hG.update = function(nD,color){
        //update domain of the y-axis to reflect change in supp
        y.domain([0,d3.max(nD,function(d){return d[1];})]);
        //attach the new data to the bars
        var bars = hGsvg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(nD);
        //transition of the height and color of rectangles
        bars.select("rect")
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr("y",function(d){return y(d[1]);})
            .attr("height",function(d){return hGDim.h - y(d[1]);})
            .attr("fill",color);
        //transition the frequency labels loc
        bars.select("text")
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .text(function(d){ return d3.format(",")(d[1]);})
            .attr("y",function(d){return y(d[1])-5;});
    };
    return hG;
}
function pieChart(pD){
    var pC={},pieDim={w:250,h:250};
    pieDim.r = Math.min(pieDim.w,pieDim.h)/2;

    //create svg for pie chart
    var piesvg = d3.select(id).append("svg")
        .attr("width",pieDim.w)
        .attr("height",pieDim.h)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(" + pieDim.w/2 + "," + pieDim.h/2 + ")");
    //create func to draw arcs of the slices
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(pieDim.r-10)
        .innerRadius(0);
    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d){return d.val;});
    //Draw the pie slices
    piesvg.selectAll("path")
        .data(pie(pD))
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d",arc)
        .each(function(d){this._current=d;})
        .style("fill",function(d){return segColor(d.data.type);})
        .on("mouseover",mouseover)
        .on("mouseout",mouseout);
    //create func to update pie-chart, this will be used by the histogram
    pC.update = function(nD){
        piesvg.selectAll("path")
            .data(pie(nD))
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attrTween("d",arcTween);
    };
    //Utility func to be called on mouseover a pie slice
    function mouseover(d){
        //call the update function of the histogram with new data
        hG.update(fData.map(function(v){
            return[v.Supplier,v.val[d.data.type]];}),segColor(d.data.type));                
    }
   //Utility func to be called on mouseout of a pie slice
    function mouseout(d){
        //call the update func of histogram with all data
        hG.update(fData.map(function(v){
            return[v.Supplier,v.total];}),barColor);
    }
    //Animate the pie-slice requiring a custom function which specifies
    //how the intermeidate paths should be draw
    function arcTween(a){
        var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
        this._current = i(0);
        return function(t){return arc(i(t));};
    }
   return pC;
}

//func to handle legend
function legend(lD){
    leg={};
    //create table for legend
    var lgend = d3.select(id)
        .append("table")
        .attr("class","legend");
    //create one row per segment
    var tr = lgend.append("tbody")
        .selectAll("tr")
        .data(lD)
        .enter()
        .append("tr");
    //create the first column for each segment
    tr.append("td")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width","16")
        .attr("height","16")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width","16")
        .attr("height","16")
        .attr("fill",function(d){return segColor(d.type);});
    //create the second column for each segment
    tr.append("td")
        .text(function(d){return d.type;});
    //create the third col
    tr.append("td")
        .attr("class","legendFreq")
        .text(function(d){return d3.format(",")(d.val);});
    //create the perc col
    tr.append("tr")
        .attr("class","legendPerc")
        .text(function(d){return getLegend(d,lD);});
    //utility func to be used to update the legend
    leg.update = function(nD){
        var l = lgend.select("tbody")
            .selectAll("tr")
            .data(nD);
        l.select(".legendFreq")
            .text(function(d){return d3.format(",")(d.val);});
        l.select(".legendPerc")
            .text(function(d){return getLegend(d,nD);});
    };
    function getLegend(d,aD){//utility func to compute perc
        return d3.format("%")(d.val/d3.sum(aD.map(function(v){return v.val;})));
    }
    return leg;

}

var sF = fData.map(function(d){
        return [d.Supplier,d.total];
});
var tF = ['WIP','Conv'].map(function(d){
    return {type:d,val:d3.sum(fData.map(function(t){return t.val[d];}))};
});
var hG = histoGram(sF),
    pC=pieChart(tF),
    leg = legend(tF);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it...

```
//create the perc col
    tr.append("tr")
        .attr("class","legendPerc")
        .text(function(d){return getLegend(d,lD);});
```

should have been...

```
//create the perc col
    tr.append("td")
        .attr("class","legendPerc")
        .text(function(d){return getLegend(d,lD);});
```