# Using D3, DC, and crossfilter for bar chart to pie chart transformation, legend percentages doesnt update

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am using D3 along with DC, and crossfilter to make bar chart to pie chart transformation having an issue of legends on right side doesn't update when i click on every bar.. please have my jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/2sgLjbvu/7/

```
 data is {Supplier:"Supplier A",val: {WIP:"500",Conv:"400",PP:"20",LL:"20"}} 

 function legend(lD){
    leg={};
    //create table for legend
    var lgend = d3.select(id)
        .append("table")
        .attr("class","legend");
    //create one row per segment
    var tr = lgend.append("tbody")
        .selectAll("tr")
        .data(lD)
        .enter()
        .append("tr");
    //create the first column for each segment
    tr.append("td")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width","16")
        .attr("height","16")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width","16")
        .attr("height","16")
        .attr("fill",function(d){return segColor(d.type);});
    //create the second column for each segment
    tr.append("td")
        .text(function(d){return d.type;});
    //create the third col
    tr.append("td")
        .attr("class","legendFreq")
        .text(function(d){return d3.format(",")(d.val);});
    //create the perc col
    tr.append("tr")
        .attr("class","legendPerc")
        .text(function(d){return getLegend(d,lD);});
    //utility func to be used to update the legend
    leg.update = function(nD){
        var l = lgend.select("tbody")
            .selectAll("tr")
            .data(nD);
        l.select(".legendFreq")
            .text(function(d){return d3.format(",")(d.val);});
        l.select(".legendPerc")
            .text(function(d){return getLegend(d,nD);});
    };
    function getLegend(d,aD){//utility func to compute perc
        return d3.format("%")(d.val/d3.sum(aD.map(function(v){return v.val;})));
    }
    return leg;

}
```

Comment: I don't see any dc.js in the code here, so not sure what that is about. The issue with clicking is that you only have mouseover handlers, so clicking on the bars does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. actualy I have got this example from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461803/d3-legend-not-updating . and I forgot to read answer post of above for the same, otherwise I wouldn't have been posted this question.